# with pyinstaller compiled exe http-server is not working/opening a port

Tags: pyinstaller, python-multithreading, python-3.9, tcpserver, socketserver

I got a simple http server which should only serve one request. In the hole Project it is for an IOT Device which gets it new Firmware via the http server.

When I execute the script withing PyCharm, everything works as expected. After I compiled it with pyinstaller it is not working at all. But I don`t get any error or warnings. Does anybody have an idea why this is not working? There is no output or errormessage when I use the PowerShell or cmd. The exe just "disapear".

My Server part (really basic stuff):

```
import http.server
import threading
import socketserver
import time

webserver_port = 7777

def thread_http():
    # open SimpleHTTPRequest handler to serve the file
    # actual the sever serves one http_get and kills it
    # if there was no correct request, the http server is stopped and no update is performed
    try:
        handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
        httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", webserver_port), handler)

        httpd.timeout = 200
        req, cltadd = httpd.get_request()
        print(f"see, it`s a request: {req} und {cltadd}")
        httpd.verify_request(req, cltadd)
        httpd.process_request(req, cltadd)

    except OSError as e:
        print(f"OS Server httpd did not started: {e}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Server httpd did not started: {e}")
def host_file():
    # host the http server as a thread
    x = threading.Thread(target=thread_http)
    x.start()

host_file()
time.sleep(15)
```

My compiling command is:

```
.\pyinstaller.exe -w --onefile C:\test_http.py --distpath C:\pyinstaller_tmp
```

Thanks in Advance.

The Server should offer/display the folder content or, if I know the Link, send the requested file.

Comment: First guess: pyinstaller extract the main.py to `somewhere-in-windows\tmp` and there is the working directory of this webserver as well. This, of couse, leads to no error, but also to no file.